# How i click to button without id?

Tags: c#, php, html, css, button

**Hello my friends,**

I'm coding a app but there is a problem. I couldn't click to button. Please help me, thanks.

**I want to click this button:**

```
<input type="button" value="Canlı Derse Başla" onclick="$j('#online_140754').show();$j('#offline_140754').hide();" style="background:#007bff;color:#ffffff;font-weight: bold;border:1px solid #007bff;border-radius: 5px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;">
```

**I used this code but it didn't work.**

```
if (url == "random")
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement nesne in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    if (nesne.GetAttribute("value") == "Canlı Derse Başla")
                    {
                        nesne.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: 20 April 2020 Monday, up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JQuery, in which the clicking of the button will be based on the class instead of the id, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        alert("the button was clicked on")
    })   
})
```

Another option is to get the elements by the tag name and looking at the inner text, for example:

```
var buttonCollection = Document.GetElementsByTagName("btn");

foreach (HtmlElement btn in buttonCollection)
{
    if (btn.InnerText == "Click here to do something")
    {
        btn.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```